CORS Issue - Between Dev and Prod
I've a problem with CORS when trying to run my ReactJS app, with my C# API when this API is hosted on my local IIS Server using HTTPS.
Here my setup detail

Front-End: ReactJS, TailWind CSS
Back-End: C# .Net 8, SQL DB, Hosted on a Local machine IIS.
Auth0 As IDProvider
I've my own domain Name, let say "MyDomain.ca"
SSL Cetificat Install on IIS

When I'm working on my Dev computer and I use my API that is also running on my Dev Machine "https://localhost:7248/api", The Web Application is working as suppose. The CORS do not block me.
When I change the API URL for my domain https://MyDomain.ca/API CORS keep bloking me.
I've install Swagger with the API, so I can do call to API. I can do Login with it whitout any problem. Swager respoind me with:
access-control-allow-credentials: true 
access-control-allow-origin: https://MyDomain.ca  
cache-control: no-cache,no-store  
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8  
date: Fri,06 Dec 2024 19:15:11 GMT  
expires: Thu,01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT  
pragma: no-cache  
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0  
vary: Origin  
x-firefox-spdy: h2  
x-powered-by: ASP.NET

But when I try wo do the login with my React App running from http://localhost:5173/ , I got error like those in the Browser Console
XHR OPTIONS https://myAuth0Domain.us.auth0.com/authorize?...blah.. CORS Missings Origin

And Also:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at

I've set my domain in the corresponding setting Auth0 application manager,
Application Login URI: https://MyDomain.ca
Allowed CallBack URL: https://MyDomain.ca/api/callback, http://localhost:5173/api/auth/callback
Allowed Web Origins: https://MyDomain.ca,http://localhost:5173
I've also set the origin in my .net API, like this:
      // [More code]

      builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
      builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
      {
          options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", corsBuilder =>
                  corsBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5173", 
                                          "https://MyDomain.ca")
                              .AllowAnyHeader()
                              .AllowAnyMethod()
                              .AllowCredentials());
      });
      // [More code]
      app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
      // [More code]

I thing that the
access-control-allow-origin: https://MyDomain.ca  

is missing from the header when I try the login from my WebApplication. But I don't know what to do to fix this.
I need some help to resolve my problem.
Thank
Hugo

you have to set your response header cors in your backend code. browser will not allow your client side to get the cross site domain without the server side giving the response with header cors that allow your client side to get the resource. I don't know how to code in C#, so I just share you what I know about cors. Hope it can help you

make sure that UseCors is called before any middleware that might handle requests

Actually the useCors command is the first just after "var app = builder.Build();"

Wanna add that setting the log level to "Trace" add a lot of usefull detail

The error is statting was CORS Error, but it has nothing to do with CORS in fact.
I've revised my whole process, an find many bug..

Auth0 M2M Application was missing (I did some clean up and deleted thing that should not have)
The way I have wrap the js fetch method was bad at some specific places
I've revised the way Auth0 ClientId, Secret was set and configured wasn't clear, so I fix this
in .NET, the ordre in witch I was registring Authentication/Autorization/ useRouting was incorrect
It shoul be

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigins");
app.UseRouting(); 
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
...
app.UseMiddleware(...) // If needed
...
app.UseSwagger(); // If needed
app.UseSwaggerUI(); // If needed
...
app.MapControllers();
...
app.Run();

then
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
        builder.Services
            .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/api/auth/login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/api/auth/logout"; // Redirect for logout
                options.Cookie.Name = "PosterityCookie";
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None; // Ensure SameSite is set to None
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; // Ensure the cookie is sent over HTTPS

                options.Events.OnSigningIn = async context =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($" options.Events.OnSigningIn {context}");
                    await Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = async context =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($" options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal {context}");
                    await Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options =>
            {
                var auth0OpenIdConfiguration = Auth0OpenIdConfiguration.CreateFromConfig(builder.Configuration);
                options.Authority = auth0OpenIdConfiguration.Authority;
                options.ClientId = auth0OpenIdConfiguration.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = auth0OpenIdConfiguration.ClientSecret;
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("email");

                options.CallbackPath = "/api/auth/callback";
                options.ClaimsIssuer = "Auth0";

                // Capture authentication event
                options.Events = OpenIdConnectEventsProvider.GetOpenIdConnectEvents();

            })


What helped me a lot is when a started to retry what I was attempting to do, but in a fresh bare bone simplified WorkBench Project, Javascript and .NET
I ate a lot of dirt before thing start working
and I learned a lot

I have had the issue on a number ocassions only to find out it has nothing to do with CORS but an error in my Controller code
   [HttpGet("TestConnect")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> TestConnect()
   {
       try
       {
         // Your Code
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
      {
          return Ok(new { Message = $"{ConnString} {ex.Message}  
          {ex.InnerException}" });
      }

       return Ok(new { Message = $"Working {ConnString}" });
    }

